# getting error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm autoloading a library named as 'render' in my codeigniter app.
the full code of the library is :

```
class Render extends CI_Controller {
    public function template($template, $view, $extra_css, $extra_js) {
        $data = array();
        if (isset($view)) {
            $data['view'] = $view;
        }
        if (isset($extra_css)) {
            $data['extra_css'] = $extra_css;
        }
        if (isset($extra_js)) {
            $data['extra_js'] = $extra_js;
        }
        $template = $this->load->view("templates/$template", $data, TRUE);
        echo $template;
    }

}
```

this library working fine but the problem is that whenever i load this library manually or by editing autoload file, i get an error when i load any model in any of my controller.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Home::$my_model_name

Filename: controllers/home.php

Line Number: 11
```

here line number 10 and 11 are :

```
$this->load->model('my_model_name');
$this->my_model_name->my_model_method();
```

and i also tried to use :

```
$this->load->model('my_model_name', 'My_model');
$this->My_model->my_model_method();
```

My controller "home" code is :

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('my_model_name');
        $this->my_model_name->index();
    }
}
```

i tried to add a __construct() method to my library but still no luck.

Comment: Can you post the code from controllers/home.php?

Comment: @Ahmed Nuaman : sure, i just edited the post, please check again.

Comment: I do not see where you are trying to load your `Render` Library... Are you trying to load it in your model `my_model_name` ????

Comment: give us the `my_model_name` code, and make sure it is in `application/models/my_model_name.php`

Comment: hi jondavidjohn, problem solved, thanks for showing concern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By doing

```
class Render extends CI_Controller
```

you're not creating a library, but a controller! In order to create a library, just create the class and put it into the libraries folder.

Inside your library, if you want to use CI's loader to load models, for ex., you need to instantiate the main CI class.

```
$CI = & get_instance();
```

Something like (file `application/libraries/render.php`) :

```
    class Render {

      var $CI;

      function __construct()
      {
        $this->CI = &get_instance();
      }

       public function template($template, $view, $extra_css, $extra_js) {
        $data = array();
        if (isset($view)) {
            $data['view'] = $view;
        }
        if (isset($extra_css)) {
            $data['extra_css'] = $extra_css;
        }
        if (isset($extra_js)) {
            $data['extra_js'] = $extra_js;
        }
        $template = $this->CI->load->view("templates/$template", $data, TRUE);
        return $template;
    }
}
```

Then you can `$CI->load` everything you want inside your library, models, other libraries, whatever.
See [Utilize CI resource within your library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) for a thorough explanation of that. The, you call your library the usual way, `$this->load->library('render')` and then `$this->render->whatever();`

Comment: thanks for your great help, you saved a lot of time of mine, i didn't slept whole night just to find a solution of this problem by googling, but you did a good job at stackoverflow, thanks a million.